# RabbitMQ Mass transit Multiple Queues as per Different Environments

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I am working on a project in .net 6 web API. I have created 2 microservices Ordering and Production. i set up is successfully. now i have 3 environments : development, Staging and UAT. for the microservices communication i used rabbitmq mass transit.

now the issue is the while i try to send some data from Ordering microservice and staging environment to Production Microservice to staging environment it is not working properly. how can i set up different rabbitmq messaging for different environments. please provide me the flow to create different rabbitmq messaging as per their environment.

i have created different environments like appsetting.development.json, appsetting.Staging.json and appsetting.UAT.json and configure the connection string as per the environment but the issue is with the rabbitmq. i am unable to configure it different so i used the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need RabbitMQ instance per environment.

Then, you have to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable in each environment to the correct value.

In your `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs`, you have to configure MassTransit using the values from configuration.

I higly suggest using [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0#the-options-pattern) for getting the values from configuration.

Comment: I  am getting the values from the configuration files. in configuration file i have setup like following: 

ServiceBus: {
Uri:"rabbitmq/localhost/",
username: "",
password:""
}

and getting these details in my class where i have created consumers and that class is included in program.cs there is no need to add startup class

Comment: that's why I said "or" :) so what's you problem then? do you have different values for the URI in each config file? do they exists? How do you deploy to the environments? Are they k8s namespaces?